# What game is this symbol from?

Tags: game-identification

I saw this in a video showing a scene from the History channel on TV. It was on a T-Shirt that was worn by a male mannequin. As far as I remember, this is from some sort of open-world game. I tried google searching it, but found no results for it.

[image: Cropped Image]

[image: Uncropped Version]

Comment: How do you know it was from a game?

Comment: @Ash I saw this in a video showing a still from the History channel on TV. So no Idea what show it was.But I feel like seeing this glowing symbol in some game

Comment: This question is being [discussed on Meta](//meta.arqade.com/q/13068)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is the logo/symbol of the [Enlightened](http://ingress.wikia.com/wiki/Enlightened), a faction in **Ingress**

[image: Enlightened]

The color of the Enlightened is usually green, while the color of the opposing faction, the Resistance, is blue. The color of the logo on the T-Shirt is quite ubiquitous in Ingress, though.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Now my question is, why was the History Channel showing a mannequin with a symbol from Ingress on its shirt?

Comment: I was actually seeing a video about LED T-shirts. In that I saw a glimpse of this. No Idea how it become historic!